# Can't ls into /home/... directory

Tags: command-line, directory

I’m a new Linux user and learning Ubuntu CLI. I’m trying to use ‘ls’ command to test the user & groups things.

so I have main user ‘beekay’ and other 2 new ones as mentioned in the text below. both can use the ls for /home/username directories howver beekay can’t
please help. below are the groups, ownerships for the folders. only problem with user beekay is that it can’t ls into /home/felipe.

```
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/yogi_v/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ su - felipe 
Password: 
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/yogi_v/
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/beekay/
Desktop    Downloads  notes.txt  Public  Templates
Documents  Music      Pictures   snap    Videos
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ logout
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/yogi_v/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads  notes.txt  Public  Templates
Documents  Music      Pictures   snap    Videos
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/
beekay  felipe  yogi_v
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/felipe/
ls: cannot open directory '/home/felipe/': Permission denied
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/felipe/
drwxr-x--- 2 root student 4096 jaan  24 20:50 /home/felipe/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ 
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/felipe/
drwxr-x--- 2 root student 4096 jaan  24 20:50 /home/felipe/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/yogi_v/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root student 4096 jaan  24 20:53 /home/yogi_v/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/beekay/
drwxr-xr-x 17 beekay beekay 4096 jaan  24 02:00 /home/beekay/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ id beekay 
uid=1000(beekay) gid=1000(beekay) groups=1000(beekay),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),1001(student)
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ id felipe 
uid=1001(felipe) gid=1002(felipe) groups=1002(felipe),1001(student)
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ id yogi_v 
uid=1002(yogi_v) gid=1003(yogi_v) groups=1003(yogi_v),1001(student)
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ su - yogi_v 
Password: 
yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/felipe/
yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/beekay/
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  notes.txt  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos
yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ logout
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ su - felipe 
Password: 
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/yogi_v/
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/beekay/
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  notes.txt  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos
felipe@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ logout
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/yogi_v/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/felipe/
ls: cannot open directory '/home/felipe/': Permission denied
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully:

```
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/felipe/
drwxr-x--- 2 root student 4096 jaan  24 20:50 /home/felipe/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/yogi_v/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root student 4096 jaan  24 20:53 /home/yogi_v/
beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls -ld /home/beekay/
drwxr-xr-x 17 beekay beekay 4096 jaan  24 02:00 /home/beekay/
```

The `/home/felipe` folder has `---` for the "other" permissions, whereas both other folders have `r-x` there. That means that `/home/felipe` is not readable for "others" (i.e., users not being `felipe` and not in `felipe`'s group).

If you want to make `/home/felipe` readable for `beekay`, `felipe` should execute this command:

```
chmod -R o+rx /home/felipe
```

or equivalently

```
chmod -R 755 /home/felipe
```

Comment: @JosAmazing!! Thanks a lot for help with this.

However, what makes me scratch my herd is that how come the user "yogi_v" can ls into the same fie/directory??


`yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/felipe/`

`yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ ls /home/beekay/`

`Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  notes.txt  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos`

`yogi_v@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ logout`

Comment: `chmod -R 755 /home/felipe`


This resolved the issue though! :)

Comment: With the information above, I can't explain why `yogi_v` can view `felipe`'s home directory. Maybe `yogi_v` is a member of `felipe`'s group, I don't know.

Comment: ok, so the Primary user `beekay` created and added both `felipe` and `yogi_v` to same group `student` later `beekay` too was added to same group.

Comment: `beekay@beekay-Ubuntu-20:~$ groups felipe beekay yogi_v` 

`felipe : felipe student`

`beekay : beekay adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare student`

`yogi_v : yogi_v student`

Comment: Thanks all. your suggestions helped me resolve the issue!